# Make zsh history search behave like bash reverse-i-search

Tags: bash, search, zsh, command-history

- In **bash**, pressing `[CTRL]+[r]` will open the `reverse-i-search` prompt.
- How can I **search the zsh history** in a similar way?

*Note:* The search query will **hit the middle of the full command** only, **instead of match at it's beginning** as required by the normal zsh search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make **zsh behave like bash** when pressing `[CTRL]+[r]`:

```
# for non-pattern search like in bash 
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward`
```

or

```
# for pattern search (the wildcard `*` will use zsh completion)
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

---

**Note:** Add the line to your `~/.zshrc` to make it permanent.